# find last same value in column x and add or deduct column y

Tags: excel

similar to a post back in May, I also need to create a sheet that includes (3) different sources of information to create a running total based on the last same value

this example is what I need to happen

```
Column A = D (to add) or W (to deduct)
Column B = Source1 or Source2 or Source3
Column C = the value that needs to be added or deducted
Column D = the running total based on the source (Column B)

A1 = D
B1 = Source1
C1 = 100
D1 = 100 (0 + C1)

A2 = W
B2 = Source1
C2 = 25
D2 = 75 (D1 - C2)

A3 = D
B3 = Source2
C3 = 50
D3 = 50 (0 + C3)

A4 = D
B4 = Source1
C4 = 100
D4 = 175 (D2 + C4)

A5 = W
B5 = Source2
C5 = 10
D5 = 40 (D3 - C5)

A6 = D
B6 = Source3
C6 = 20
D6 = 20 (0 + C6)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Have tried inserting a picture, however as I am a new to the site I am unable to...sorry about that

I am using this which adds correctly

```
=SUMIFS($C$1:$C1, $A$1:$A1, A1, $B$1:$B1, B1)
```

however, I also need to make it deduct if Column A = W

Comment: See [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-9DD6179E-CCED-41DD-AC38-08FDF5B929E5) and lookup relative vs absolute cell addresses.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you showed an example sheet and used that to describe what you want. Since this is a new account, there is no way we can see your May post.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in cell D1 and copy it down: `=SUMIFS($C$1:$C1,$B$1:$B1,B1,$A$1:$A1,"D")-SUMIFS($C$1:$C1,$B$1:$B1,B1,$A$1:$A1,"W")`.

I was able to get started using the formula that you provided. I modified it so that it subtracted a running total of W's for each source from a running total of D's for each source.